# Change buttons title after initialized

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I downloaded a custom `alertView` from [github - DOAlertController](https://github.com/okmr-d/DOAlertController). I followed the right steps to create the `alertView`. Here's what I have:

```
let alertController = DOAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .Alert)

var okAction = DOAlertAction!
self.okAction = DOAlertAction(title: "OK" style: .Default) { action in
    self.okAction.title = "myTitle"
    println(self.okAction.Title)
}
```

After `okAction` is clicked on, I want to change its title. I tried that, and it doesn't change. But the `println` logs `myTitle`.

How can I change a `buttons` title later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the label's text is set in [the `layoutView()` method](https://github.com/okmr-d/DOAlertController/blob/master/DOAlertController/DOAlertController.swift#L430):

```
func layoutView() {
    if (layoutFlg) { return }
    layoutFlg = true

    // snip

    let hasTitle: Bool = title != nil && title != ""

    // snip

    if (hasTitle) {
        // snip
        titleLabel.text = title
        // snip
    }

    // snip
}
```

So you could either just set `titleLabel.text` yourself or set `layoutFlg` to `false` and call `layoutView()` again. However, both of those variables are declared `private`, so you'll need to remove that declaration to be able to change them.

A third option would be to create a `didSet` block on the `title` variable. Something like this should work:

```
var title: String {
    didSet {
        titleLabel.text = title
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Where would I put `didSet...`?

Comment: There's another `didSet` already in that code under `var enabled` if you want to see what it looks like

Comment: I just tried that. It gives me an error: "`Use of unresolved identifier 'titleLabel'`". I think it's giving that because `titleLabel` is created later in the program.

Comment: @Jessica Oh yeah, you're right. You'll need to make `titleLabel` a property, or try one of the other approaches I mentioned. The way this code is written, the title is not meant to be changed later.